# snakemake access config in output

Tags: output, wildcard, expand, rule, snakemake

Using snakemake, I'm interested in splitting a bam file by it's overlap with a set of targets. Each output file will then be named something like `{sample}_{target}.bam`. The set of targets are defined by a bed file per sample. I would like to do this using the following rule setup:

```
rule break_bam:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: config['Samples'][wildcards.sample]['input_bam']
    output:
        expand("{{sample}}_{target}.bam",target=get_targets(config['Samples][wildcards.sample]['bed_file']))
    run:
        shell(" break_bam {input} ")
```

In my example, 'get_targets' is a function to extract the name column from the bed file.

Question: I've tried a number of different methods of accessing the wildcard-accessible path when setting the rule output, but I haven't yet gotten it to work. Does a method currently exist to dynamically access the config file in this way?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: Maybe you should also show the relevant parts of your config file. It seems that each sample is split according to a specific bed file. Could you add an explanation why? If these bed files are generated by your workflow, it would make sense to use the sample name in the name of the corresponding bed file. Also, it seems strange that the bed files are not part of the input of your rule.